# why table User not creat ? I get this msg " Unsuccessful: create table user"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a project in Spring-boot.
Sorry for bad English guys.
So, problem is: when i run my project by "bootRun", 2 of 3 tables only created in my postgresql database. They are "role" and "user_role". And the Hibernate return a message, when it try to create the third table "user". This is the message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAJAo.png)

this is user.java code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        super();
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.login = user.getLogin();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

this is role.java code

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role(String name, Set<User> users) {
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role() {
    }
}
```

application.properties file

```
spring.profiles.active=dev

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=12345

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.RC1")
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"

jar {
    baseName = "spring-rest-service-oauth"
    version =  "0.1.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

dependencies {
//  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path")
    testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "2.7"
}
```

thanks who respond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `User` is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

you can escape your table name to avoid reserved keyword as below

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"User\"")
public class User
```

Answer (score 1):

Check SQL reserved words for PostgreSQL: [Appendix B. SQL Key Words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)